# Zend 1.12 displaying a twitter feed

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, twitter

I am needing a twitter feed displayed in my zend website, just the feed, nothing else, so far everything I have tried either hasn't worked or has been unsuitable (for instance directly embedding the feed into the views html)

Currently I have a 'TwitterController.php' I have added a 'Twitter.php' script to the /zend/service/twitter/ folder as there wasn't one present and I have tried using the following code to no success

```
$token = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();

        $token->setParams(array(
            'oauth_token'        => 'mytoken',
            'oauth_token_secret' => 'mytokensecret',
        ));

        $twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
        'username'       => 'myname',
        'consumerKey'    => 'mykey',
        'consumerSecret' => 'mysecret',
        'accessToken'    => $token
        ));
```

The feed is to be displayed on my home page so I have tried this code in both IndexController and TwitterController.

This is surely easier than I have made it?

edit - I have added the following code to my IndexController and I have deleted the Twitter.php file, 'twas redundant.

```
// Create options array
        $options = array('accessToken' => $token);



// Request data from Twitter (20 most recent statuses posted from the authenticating user)
        $this->view->twitter_timeline = $twitter->status->userTimeline();
```

My view currently only has this piece of code in it:

```
<?php   $tweet = $this -> post -> text;?>
```

Which is throwing the error

```
exception 'Zend_Service_Twitter_Exception' with message 'Invalid method type "status"'
```

It may also be worthy noting my twitter account currently only has 1 tweet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tweak this slightly to:

```
$twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
    'username'       => 'myname',
    'accessToken'    => $token,
    'oauthOptions'   => array(
        'consumerKey'    => 'mykey',
        'consumerSecret' => 'mysecret',
    )
));
```

I'm slightly unsure what you mean your comment that you've added "a 'Twitter.php' script to the /zend/service/twitter/ folder" - you should never add files to the Zend folder, so if the above doesn't work perhaps you could explain what you mean by that a bit more.

Comment: Yeah I had read a few examples of achieving this, when there is a call to 'Zend_Service_Twitter' it unnerved me there was only 'exception' & 'response' present in the folder, I incorrectly assumed there was something I was missing from the installation, I have removed the Twitter.php script now, also where am i meant to be adding this? and does this not requre the use of a controller?

Comment: Class names map directly to filenames, so you'll find the twitter service at `Zend/Service/Twitter.php` rather than in the Twitter folder. You said in your question you had a controller - how were you planning on calling the service from that?

Comment: good point, I have your above example in my IndexController is this correct? As far as I am aware this is all that is needed however I still don't know how to output this in my index view?

Comment: It should be `$twitter->statuses->userTimeline()` (note plural 'statuses'). Unfortunately the ZF1 docs for this service are quite out of date. You might want to try storing `$twitter->statuses->userTimeline()->toValue()` which will give you a stdClass of the JSON result.

Comment: I had got this far before, but now I am getting "exception 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Unable to Connect to ssl://api.twitter.com:443" I am developing this locally is that an issue?

Comment: It should work fine locally. https://api.twitter.com is the right address, so you'll need to see if you can work out why it can't connect to that. See if you can view https://api.twitter.com/ in a browser (it will give you a 404 page if it works).

Comment: I can view that page just fine...would this require a new question?

Comment: Probably yes. Include the full trace in the error if you can. Your local installation might be missing openssl (which would prevent PHP from connecting to SSL addresses)